# Why does the import failed to pull class in in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

I am following this example:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pytest.html

I created two classes: Car.py and test_car_pytest.py under the src/ project:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, speed=0):
        self.speed = speed
        self.odometer = 0
        self.time = 0
   ...
```

and then in test_car_pytest.py:

```
from Car import Car

def test_car_brake():
    car = Car(50)
    assert car.speed == 45
```

In PyCharm, the import statement shows that 'Car' is an unresolved reference. When I tried to run it, I got the following error:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-4.2.0, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1
rootdir: /Users/minn/PycharmProjects/test/src, inifile:
test_car_pytest.py:None (test_car_pytest.py)
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/minn/PycharmProjects/test/src/test_car_pytest.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test_car_pytest.py:1: in <module>
    from Car import Car
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Car'
```

When I execute Car.py separately, it runs normally. The 2 files are under the same directory, why does the import fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Python 3, you'll need a relative import. Change your import statement to the following:

```
from .Car import Car
```